# Implement surface blur in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Please help me implement **Surface blur** (like Photoshop) in **OpenCV, Python**. I spent a lot of time to searching it, but I found nothing.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the code and the different ways you've tried to implement this.

Comment: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html, https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the description given [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/blur-filters.html#surface_blur) of the surface blur filter, you can use [bilateral filtering](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga9d7064d478c95d60003cf839430737ed).
I'm qouting from the above link.

> The Surface Blur filter blurs an image while preserving edges. This
> filter is useful for creating special effects and for removing noise
> and graininess.

Also check [here](https://blog.photopea.com/surface-blur-and-median.html) and [here](http://www.shellandslate.com/fastmedian.html) for additional details and [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) opencv tutorial on filtering.

In the example below, I'm using the image given in the shellandslate site.

```
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread('input.png')
blur = cv.bilateralFilter(im,9,75,75)
```

Result:

[image: input]
[image: blur]

Answer (score 0):

Try `cv2.filter2D` function

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
img = cv2.imread('imagename.extension')
blurred = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
cv2.imwrite('blurred_image.extension', blurred)
```